# Autofill post meta wordpress PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to make a script which autofilled post meta in wordpress, I did one on javascript but I need on PHP and I don't know exactly how can I do it on PHP.

This is in Javascript(it works).

```
var imdbid = $('input[name=Checkbx2]').get(0).value;
    $.getJSON("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=" + imdbid + "&plot=full&tomatoes=true", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            if(key == "Year"){
                $('#input[name=year]').val(val);
            }
        });
    });
```

Can you told me which is equivalence in php of `$('#input[name=year]').val(val);` ?

Comment: `<input type = "text" value="<?php echo $your_value; ?>">`

Comment: This will not auto complete the input.